# How to call function after ".", javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this sample function, and i want to call it in this format :

```
const myfunc = (string) => {
   return string.length
}

console.log("check_length".myfunc())
```

How can i do that?
Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: So you would have to extend the string prototype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way is to mutate the prototype of `String` with a classic function for accessing `this`.

```js
String.prototype.myfunc = function () {
   return this.length;
};

console.log("check_length".myfunc());
```

Comment: Correct. Also, please, **never ever actually do that.**